# Maybe I wrote a virus by mistake?

Tags: c, windows

When I run below code it works until 3 iterations of simple game but after the 3rd iteration CPU usage shoots to 90% and instantly crashes. Even console is terminated but below programs exe is seen in windows task list. I have to manually delete it for windows CPU to return to 3% levels.
Do you know what causes this? (I use Dev-C++ on windows 7 64 bit machine)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void game(void);
int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    game();
    return 0;
}
void game(void) {
    int choice = 1;
    while (choice != 0) {
        int number1, number2, resultStudent, result;
        number1 = 1 + rand() % 9;
        number2 = 1 + rand() % 9;
        result = number1 * number2;
        printf("How much is %d times %d ?", number1, number2);
        scanf("%d", & resultStudent);
        while (resultStudent != result) {
            printf("No. Please try again.");
            scanf("%d", &resultStudent);
        }
        printf("Very Good\n");
        printf("Do you wanna play again?(0 for Exit):  ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);
        printf("Hmm you wanna play again...\n");
    }
    printf("Program is terminated.");
}
```

Comment: Pedantic:  that's not a virus

Comment: Even I don't konw why this thing crashed windows.

Comment: its called a bug. Completely different creature.

Comment: There is also a 'debugger' creature.

Comment: Real answer: If you (intentonally or accidentaly) input "y" or "yes" as an answer to the question of whether you want to continue, the program will try to read that text it as a number, again and again, in a loop, and this may cause high cpu load, or the window it runs in to close. Not a virus.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves all the downvotes. It's certainly not a virus, but it's a moderately interesting bug. (Consistently checking the value returned by `scanf` would have been a good way to catch it.)

Comment: Indeed, my +1 because though the title might be a tad hilarious to the IT-savvy, the OP simply didn't understand the behaviour, and apparently panicked a little on the sheer number of unexpected symptoms. I actually commend this: *he noticed the CPU load, console closing* etc. Paying attention is the first thing required when learning.

Comment: Thanks for your nice words:)

Comment: You should consider upgrading your compiler (if at all possible) to GCC. Dev C++ is severely outdated.

Comment: My compiler is also TDM-GCC 4.6.1 64 bit in DevC++

Comment: I love the idea of a virus that prompts you to answer simple math questions.

Comment: @Rapptz: As I recall Dev C++ is an IDE; it can probably be configured to use more recent compilers.

Comment: Since nobody can post an answer, I'll summarize. 1. `scanf()` returns a result. Read the documentation to find out what it means, and always check it. If it fails, don't blindly continue executing. 2. If `scanf()` sees a letter while trying to read an integer, it will push that letter back onto `stdin`, where the next `scanf("%d", ...)` will do the same thing again. That's the cause of your infinite loop. 3. If you're expecting integer input, at least tell the user. Better, permit `y` or `n` for a yes/no question (dealing with inputs other than `y` or `n` is left as an exercise).

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy your comment should really be an answer. :-)  And it also loops forever if you type 'n' for "No".

Comment: I downloaded DEV-C++ 5.4.1 RC4. This time code worked okay. I do not know what caused the problem with former version but I am happy that I have a working IDE now. 

Note: I changed Compiler to MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32-bit. In former version it was TDM-GCC 64 bit compiler. I am using 32 bit compiler in a 64 bit machine. I do not have any idea if this is healthy or not but it works.

Comment: As a side note, the problem was not I accidentally hit character instead of a number. The problem was after 3 or 4 iterations of the game loop, I hit a number and .exe crashes. Even I hit a y or any char, CPU shoots to %55 max(I tried). In my case after 3r iteration, CPU overshooted to %90's.

Comment: It _might_ be a virus. I remember falling asleep at the keyboard one afternoon and, when I lifted my drooling face of the keys half an hour later, I found I'd created a fully-blown, plugin-capable IDE :-)