# DevC++ crashes this code but Visual Studio 2008 runs without problems. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dev-c++

When I run below code in DevC++ (Version 4.9.9.2 Orwell Update 5.3.0.3 which uses TDM-GCC 4.6.1.64 compiler)it works until 3 iterations of simple game but after the 3rd or 4th iteration CPU usage shoots to 90% and instantly crashes. Even console is terminated but below programs exe is seen in windows task list. I have to manually delete it for windows CPU to return to 3% levels.

But when I run this code in Windows Visual Studio 2008 Professional it works nicely.
Do you know what causes this? (My computer is Windows 7 64 bit machine)

I really love DevC++ and I want to use it. I just don't like Visual Studio. 
But if it makes program crashes often(Maybe code is wrong I have no idea but this code works in Visual Studio??) I have to use Visual Studio from now on.

Please respond. Maybe my DevC++ is defective?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void game(void);

int main(void) {

srand(time(NULL));
game();

return 0;

}

void game(void){

int choice=1;
while(choice!=0){

                int number1,number2,resultStudent,result,aha;

                number1=1+rand()%9;
                number2=1+rand()%9;
                result=number1*number2;

                printf("How much is %d times %d ?",number1,number2);
                scanf("%d",&resultStudent);

                    while (resultStudent!=result) {

                        printf("No. Please try again.");
                        scanf("%d",&resultStudent);


                    }

                printf("Very Good\n");
                printf("Do you wanna play again?(0 for Exit):  ");
                scanf("%d",&aha);

                choice=aha;

                printf("Hmm you wanna play again...\n");


}

printf("Program is terminated.");

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maybe I wrote a virus by mistake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044660/maybe-i-wrote-a-virus-by-mistake)

Comment: There was a comment on the other question that looked like a plausible answer, did you take it into consideration?

Comment: Hello Mark, Indeed I did not understand their answer. So I wrote it here also. But if there is a problem how Visual Studio runs without problems?

Comment: He suggested that I accidentally pressed a character instead of a number so this caused infinite loop but I tried so many times with caution and I did not press any character accidentally. There is something wrong with the compiler I think. I do not want to accuse of course any compiler but I become worried if it crashes on a simple program like this, how will I be able to make bigger programs with the IDE?

Comment: I downloaded DEV-C++ 5.4.1 RC4. This time code worked okay. I do not know what caused the problem with former version but I am happy that I have a working IDE now. 

Note: I changed Compiler to MinGW GCC 4.7.2 32-bit. In former version it was TDM-GCC 64 bit compiler.